# tensorflow.keras can`t fitting because of bert error

Tags: tf.keras, bert-language-model

I fitting this code and have error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jan  7 22:32:22 2023

@author: User
"""


__author__ = 'jf'
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from Matching import LinearMatching1D
from att import *
from load import getdataset
from Self_layer import *
import numpy as np

#from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel, BertConfig
import torch

#mport tensorflow as tf
#tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() # 关键

from keras_bert import load_vocabulary
from keras_bert import Tokenizer as tokenizer
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

config_path = 'D:/Anaconda/Joint Model Research2/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = 'D:/Anaconda/Joint Model Research2/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model.ckpt'
dict_path = 'D:/Anaconda/Joint Model Research2/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/vocab.txt'

bert_model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path, seq_len=None)

#bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
def sub_model(att1,att2,atttopic,DENSE_SIZE,LOSS):
    #增加结构门控语义网络
    #gated_DIM=int(att1.shape[-1])
    #print("encoded_structure.shape：",encoded_structure.shape)#(?, 32)
    #print("att1.shape：",att1.shape)#(?, 64)
    #quit()
    #multiStructure_1=SGSN_layer(gated_DIM,encoded_structure,att1)
    #print("multiStructure_1.shape:",multiStructure_1.shape)
    #multiStructure_2=SGSN_layer(gated_DIM,encoded_structure,att2)
    #print("multiStructure_2.shape:",multiStructure_2.shape)
    #增加主题门控语义网络
    #gated_DIM=int(att1.shape[-1])
    #multi_topic1=SGSN_layer(gated_DIM,atttopic,att1)
    #multi_topic2=SGSN_layer(gated_DIM,atttopic,att2)
    ##融合向量
    #merged_vector = concatenate([att1,multiStructure_1,att2,multi_topic1,multiStructure_2,multi_topic2,atttopic])
    merged_vector = concatenate([att1,att2,atttopic])
    ##全连接
    dense = Dense(DENSE_SIZE, activation='relu')(merged_vector)
    ##随机损失
    output = Dropout(LOSS)(dense)
    return output

def SGSNAll_LSTM_Nostructure(modelname="",
                            data={},
                            embedding_dim=300,
                            lstmsize=32,
                            batch_size=80,
                            epoch=100,
                            dense_size=64,
                            category_size=3,
                            loss=0.5,
                            max_sequence_length=300):
    ##超参数的设置
    ##向量的维度
    EMBEDDING_DIM=embedding_dim
    POS_EMBEDDING_DIM=50
    #每次的数目
    BATCH_SIZE=batch_size
    #迭代次数
    EPOCH=epoch
    LSTMSIZE=lstmsize
    #所有词的总个数
    num_words=0;
    #word2Vec向量路径
    WORD2VEC_BIN="./Google_word2vec_zhwiki1710_300d.bin"
    MODEL_SAVE_DIR="./"+str(modelname)
    if os.path.exists(MODEL_SAVE_DIR):
        pass;
    else:
        os.mkdir(MODEL_SAVE_DIR)
    #最后隐藏层
    DENSE_SIZE=dense_size
    #最后分类个数
    CATEGRORYSIZE=category_size
    #随机损失比
    LOSS=loss
    #最长文本长度
    MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=max_sequence_length
    result_dic = data;
    tokenizer = result_dic['tokenizer']
    #embeddings_dic形式为“词：向量”；
    embeddings_dic = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(WORD2VEC_BIN, binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
    #word_index形式为"词：序号";
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    #样本中词的数目+1
    num_words = len(word_index)+1
    #创建映射矩阵，行为词的个数，列为词向量长度。
    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
    #对于样本中的每一个词及编号
    for word, i in word_index.items():
        #如果有词向量
        if word in embeddings_dic:
            embedding_matrix[i] = embeddings_dic[word]
    ## word embedding
    embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                trainable=False)
    # pos embedding
    pos_tokenizer = result_dic['tokenizer_pos']
    pos_index = pos_tokenizer.word_index
    num_pos = len(pos_index)+1
    pos_embedding_layer = Embedding(num_pos, POS_EMBEDDING_DIM)

    #####构造模型
    ##设定输入
    sequence_input_1 = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,))
    sequence_input_2 = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,))
    #pos_input_1=Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    #pos_input_2=Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    #sequence_input_topic=Input(shape=(30,), dtype='int32')
    #pos_input_topic=Input(shape=(30,), dtype='int32')

    #start1=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #end1=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #fromstart1=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #fromend1=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #size1=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

    #start2=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #end2=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #fromstart2=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #fromend2=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    #size2=Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')


    #print(sequence_input_1_list)
    #quit()
    print("sequence_input_1:",sequence_input_1)
    print("sequence_input_2:",sequence_input_2)
    K = bert_model([sequence_input_1, sequence_input_2])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(K)
    ###使用LSTM+Att来编码信息
    #merged_input_1 = Concate_wordandpos_layer(pos_input_1,sequence_input_1,pos_embedding_layer,embedding_layer)
    #merged_input_2 = Concate_wordandpos_layer(pos_input_2,sequence_input_2,pos_embedding_layer,embedding_layer)
    #merged_topic=Concate_wordandpos_layer(pos_input_topic,sequence_input_topic,pos_embedding_layer,embedding_layer)
    #print("merged_input_1.shape:",merged_input_1.shape)#(?, 300, 350)
    #print("merged_input_2.shape:",merged_input_2.shape)#(?, 300, 350)
    #print("merged_topic.shape:",merged_topic.shape)#(?, 300, 350)
    ##构建篇章单元1,2的LSTM
    #sharedlstm=Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(LSTMSIZE,return_sequences=True))
    #encoded_text_1=sharedlstm(sequence_input_1)
    #encoded_text_2=sharedlstm(sequence_input_2)
    #print("encoded_text_1.shape:",encoded_text_1.shape)#(?, 300, 64)
    #print("encoded_text_2.shape:",encoded_text_2.shape)#(?, 300, 64)
    #主题单元
    #sharedlstm2=Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(LSTMSIZE,return_sequences=True))
    #encoded_topic=sharedlstm2(sequence_input_topic)
    #print("encoded_topic.shape:",encoded_topic.shape)#("bidirectional_2/concat_2:0", shape=(?, 30, 64), dtype=float32)
    ##构建Attention
    #shareAtttopic1=Attention()
    #print("encoded_topic:",encoded_topic)#("bidirectional_2/concat_2:0", shape=(?, 30, 64), dtype=float32)
    #atttopic=shareAtttopic1(encoded_topic)
    #print("atttopic.shape:",atttopic.shape)#(?, 64)
    #quit()
    #shareAtt1=Attention()
    ##共享attention
    #att1=shareAtt1(encoded_text_1)
    #att2=shareAtt1(encoded_text_2)
    #print("encoded_text_1:",encoded_text_1)#Tensor("bidirectional_1/concat_2:0", shape=(?, 300, 64), dtype=float32)
    #print("encoded_text_2:",encoded_text_2)#encoded_text_2: Tensor("bidirectional_1_1/concat_2:0", shape=(?, 300, 64), dtype=float32)
    #print("encoded_topic:",encoded_topic)#encoded_topic: Tensor("bidirectional_2/concat_2:0", shape=(?, 30, 64), dtype=float32)
    #获取到结构编码信息
    #encoded_structure=strucutre_encoding_layer(result_dic,32,start1,end1,fromstart1,fromend1,size1,start2,end2,fromstart2,fromend2,size2)
    #print("encoded_structure.shape:",encoded_structure.shape)#(?, 32)
    #联合输出
    #total_output=sub_model(sequence_input_1,sequence_input_2,sequence_input_topic,DENSE_SIZE,LOSS)
    #print("n_output:",n_output)
    #print("r_output:",r_output)
    #最终预测结果，3分类
    #c_output=Dense(DENSE_SIZE, activation='relu')(concatenate([n_output,r_output]))
    #rf_output=concatenate([r_output,c_output])
    #print("n_output.shape:",n_output.shape)
    #print("rf_output.shape:",rf_output.shape)
    #quit()
    n_preds = Dense(CATEGRORYSIZE, activation='softmax')(x)
    r_preds= Dense(CATEGRORYSIZE, activation='softmax')(x)
    #构建一个输入有2个的输出有2个的模型
    model = Model(inputs=[sequence_input_1, sequence_input_2
                          ],
                  outputs=[n_preds,r_preds])
    
    #model = Model(inputs=[sequence_input_1, sequence_input_2,
                          #pos_input_1,pos_input_2,
                          #sequence_input_topic,pos_input_topic,
                          #start1,start2,
                          #end1,end2,
                          #fromstart1,fromstart2,
                          #fromend1,fromend2,
                          #size1,size2], outputs=[n_preds,r_preds])
    #model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
    #对模型进行编译，loss是交叉熵
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  loss_weights=[0.2, 0.8],
                  metrics=['acc'])
    x_train,y_train=getdataset(result_dic,'train',"all")
    x_valid,y_valid=getdataset(result_dic,'test',"all")
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join(MODEL_SAVE_DIR, 'Model-{epoch:02d}.hdf5'),
                                   monitor="val_acc",save_best_only=False,
                                   verbose=1)
    model.summary()
    print("OK")
    #进行模型训练
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,
              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
              epochs=EPOCH,
              validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid),
              callbacks=[checkpointer])


def trible_sim(att1,att2):
    sen_cos_sim=dot([att1,att2],axes=-1,normalize=True)
    shared_sim=LinearMatching1D()
    sen_sim=shared_sim([att1,att2])
    sen_matchsim=Dense(250,activation='tanh')(Concatenate()([att1,att2]))
    return concatenate([sen_cos_sim,sen_sim,sen_matchsim])
```

This is model and Error

Model: "model_2"

---

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 300)]        0

---

input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 300)]        0

---

model_1 (Model)                 multiple             101677056   input_1[0][0]
input_2[0][0]

---

lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 768)          0           model_1[1][0]

---

dense (Dense)                   (None, 3)            2307        lambda[0][0]

---

## dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 3)            2307        lambda[0][0]

Total params: 101,681,670
Trainable params: 4,614
Non-trainable params: 101,677,056

---

OK
Train on 4766 samples, validate on 1294 samples
Epoch 1/10
2023-01-19 22:18:43.938518: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:619 : Not found: Resource localhost/Embedding-Segment/embeddings/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
2023-01-19 22:18:43.938531: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at resource_variable_ops.cc:619 : Not found: Resource localhost/Embedding-Token/embeddings/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mainExperience.py", line 189, in 
BERT_nostructure(data,modelname=modelname,lstmsize=LSTMSIZE,epoch=epoch,dense_size=DENSIZE,loss=LOSS)
File "mainExperience.py", line 174, in BERT_nostructure
SGSNAll_LSTM_Nostructure(modelname=modelname,lstmsize=lstmsize,data=data,epoch=epoch,dense_size=dense_size,loss=loss);
File "D:\Anaconda\Joint Model Research2\BERTmodel.py", line 229, in SGSNAll_LSTM_Nostructure
callbacks=[checkpointer])
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\reasearch\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 780, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\reasearch\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\reasearch\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3292, in **call**
run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\reasearch\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in **call**
run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention_bv from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention_bv/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
[[{{node model_1/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/add_2/ReadVariableOp}}]]
[[metrics/dense_1_acc/Identity/_135]]
(1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention_bv from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention_bv/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
[[{{node model_1/Encoder-10-MultiHeadSelfAttention/add_2/ReadVariableOp}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

what happen about this code,these seen bert error?I try to figure out this happen